# How do I test the setup.py for my package?

Tags: python, integration-testing, setup.py

I have a pretty big Python package I've written, about 3500 statements, with a robust unit and acceptance test suite. I feel quite confident about the quality of the code itself, but I'm uneasy about the install process going smoothly for users of the package as I don't know how to reliably test the install in an appropriately isolated environment, short of something like keeping a spare machine around and re-imaging it with a fresh OS install for each test run.

I suspect using virtualenv in the right way might provide a proper test fixture for testing installation, but after extended web searches have uncovered no helpful guidance.

How can I effectively test my setup.py and other installation bits on my development machine?

Comment: Why just not try `python setup.py install` in virtualenv?

Comment: How do I know that's not making use of files or other dependencies present on my development machine that won't be in the environment of an end-user?

Comment: If you feel that you cannot trust that virtualenv does what you want you could try a virtual machine. Grab VirtualBox install and take a snapshot, then you can run setup.py and restore snapshot to get back to clean state. Virtual Machines are useful for a ton of other things also. :) Yes it is overkill for this but not as overkill as a separate physical machine.

Comment: I don't mind trusting virtualenv, I was just hoping that someone had worked out exactly what levels and types of isolation it provides and had established confidence that, used in a particular way, perhaps with certain options or precautions, it would provide a reliable installation test fixture. I've done the installation with virtualenv, and use tox (which uses virtualenv) to test against various Python versions. What I don't know is how far I can trust successful installs there to catch install problems others might face.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like tools (*which I do*) check out [fabric](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric/1.8.0) and the set of Fabric tasks I've written across all my projects:

e.g: [circuits' fabfile](https://github.com/circuits/circuits/tree/master/fabfile)

This should work for just about any Python project and utilizes:

- Sphinx
- py.test/tox
- virtualenv

Some basic workflows:

```
fab build    # build the package in non-development mode
fab develop  # build the package in development mode
fab docs     # build/regenerate the documentation
fab test     # run tie unit test suite
fab release  # run through a tested release cycle
```

Type: `fab -l` for a list of commands and `fab help:<name>` for help on any command.

**Update:** Recently we added `fab docker` commands to work with [Docker](https://www.docker.com)

```
fab docker:build    # Build a Docker image
fab docker:publish  # Publish Docker image to the Docker Hub
fab docker:run      # Run a new Docker container
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks interesting. So you keep a separate machine running somewhere to act as a deployment test fixture? This actually brings to mind a continuous integration (CI) environment as a possible option. Maybe I should consider putting the package up on Travis CI or something. I've briefly considered that a while ago but hadn't really researched it.

Comment: No, the fabric tasks are all local only. I do however push all my projects to both drono.io and shiningpanda.com CI services -- but this ia handled automatically by repository hooks by BitBucket.

Comment: Hmm, that IS interesting. So where on your local machine do you actually do the building? How do you get isolation and does it increase your confidence in your build scripts/setup.py? I guess my other question is why you need to use fabric instead of just a bash script if there is no SSH connection involved? Or is there?

Comment: Best you study my code :) I use Fabric because a) I don't like Bash and b) Python + Frabric is a little more flexible. Yes "fab test" and "fab release" are done in isolation using virtualenv.

Comment: Ok, but conceptually at least, you're saying you do it with a shell script (happens to be Python+Fabric), into a virtualenv in a separate directory on your development box. k, that gives me some ideas. I guess if I'm building the package in my dev directory and then installing *from that package* into an isolated virtualenv, that's a pretty decent test. Better than none anyway :)  It wouldn't detect things like C-library dependencies, but it seems like more than half-way there, short of setting up a battery of refreshable different OS environments :)

Comment: Yes basically. And yes it would detect missing C-libraries if you extneded my idea to do something like: 1) Create a new OpenVZ/KVM instance on a Virtualization Platform 2) Spin up a new VirtualEnv 3) Do your install/setup, etc...

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking setting up a virtual OS install is one step beyond the time I'm willing to invest in it :) But this has been very helpful discussion for me; I feel like I understand the problem and possible solution domains well enough now to decide on the solution for my current situation. Thanks for your help, I'm awarding you the virtual prize! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you **really** want isolation instead just doing `python setup.py install` in virtualenv. Then use virtualbox and install some free linux os in it. Take a snapshot of the machine after the install so you can revert easily with one click to the starting point at any time and try `python setup.py install` there.

Answer (score 0):

I think basic `tox` config does this job automatically.